# How to display other data if object doesn't exist in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

Alright, I am passing way too much time on this one, seems completely trivial but somehow I can **not** sort it out.

I am trying to display the data from an object to my DOM :

```
// Listen to every people in our query...
  geoQuery40.on("key_entered", function(key) {
    // ... and look them up by key ...
    restaurantsRef40.child(key).on("value", function(snapshot42) {
      var restaurant40 = snapshot42.val();
      console.log(restaurant40);
      var displayBusinessName = snapshot42.val().name;
      console.log(displayBusinessName);
      var displayBusinessDescription = snapshot42.val().description;
      $timeout(function() {
        if (snapshot42.exists()) {
          $timeout(function() {
      $scope.displayBusinessName = displayBusinessName;
      $scope.displayBusinessDescription = displayBusinessDescription;
    })
    } else {
      $timeout(function() {
      $scope.displayBusinessName = "displayBusinessName";
      $scope.displayBusinessDescription = "displayBusinessDescription";
    })
    }
    })
    });
  });
```

Now, if the **snapshot42** is empty / has nothing, I want to redefine what I show. It just doesn't work.

Here is my DOM :

```
<div class="content2" ng-controller="businessPageController">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="profile-info">
                <!-- *profile-image / image profile -->
                <img class="profile-image" src="img/100.jpg">
                <!-- *profile-name / name profile -->
                <h3 class="profile-name">{{displayBusinessName}}</h3>
                <!-- *profile-description / description profile -->
                <span class="profile-description">
                    {{displayBusinessDescription}}
                </span>
        <br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Just a heads-up that isn't necessarily related to your issue. When using `.on('value', [callback])` you're actually registering a listener for value change events. So your callback may be executed even if the "key_entered" event isn't fired a second time. If you only want to retrieve the value one time, when a "key_entered" event is triggered, you should use `once('value', [callback])` - or better yet `once('value').then(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you attempt to access the value, before checking whether the value even exists. I.e. you call `snapshot42.val().name` before calling `snapshot42.exists()`. If the value doesn't exist, `snapshot42.val()` will return null, which will throw an error saying `Cannot read property 'name' of null` once you try to access properties on it.
You havn't provided any information regarding any error messages though, so it's just a shot in the dark.

Anyways, if the above is in fact the problem, the following changes would solve them:

```
geoQuery40.on("key_entered", function(key) {
    // ... and look them up by key ...
    restaurantsRef40.child(key).once("value", function(snapshot42) {
        if(snapshot42.exists()){
            var restaurant40 = snapshot42.val();
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.displayBusinessName = restaurant40.name;
                $scope.displayBusinessDescription = restaurant40.description;
            });
        }else{
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.displayBusinessName = "displayBusinessName";
                $scope.displayBusinessDescription = "displayBusinessDescription";
            });
        }
    });
});
```